# How can i get UTCTime in millisecond since January 1, 1970 in c language

Tags: c, time.h

Is there any way to get milliseconds and its fraction part from 1970 using time.h in c language?

Comment: You can't get the fraction part in a platform independent way. Which platform are you focusing on?

Comment: I am following the standard of ANSI C, so that my application will be platform independent. Currently I am on window platform.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

This works on Ubuntu Linux:

```
#include <sys/time.h>

...

struct timeval tv;

gettimeofday(&tv, NULL);

unsigned long long millisecondsSinceEpoch =
    (unsigned long long)(tv.tv_sec) * 1000 +
    (unsigned long long)(tv.tv_usec) / 1000;

printf("%llu\n", millisecondsSinceEpoch);
```

At the time of this writing, the printf() above is giving me 1338850197035. You can do a sanity check at the [TimestampConvert.com](http://www.timestampconvert.com/) website where you can enter the value to get back the equivalent human-readable time (albeit without millisecond precision).

Answer (score 12):

If you want millisecond resolution, you can use gettimeofday() in Posix. For a Windows implementation see [gettimeofday function for windows](http://www.cpp-programming.net/c-tidbits/gettimeofday-function-for-windows/).

```
#include <sys/time.h>

...

struct timeval tp;
gettimeofday(&tp);
long int ms = tp.tv_sec * 1000 + tp.tv_usec / 1000;
```

Comment: It should probably be `gettimeofday (&tv, NULL)`

Comment: The link in the answer is dead. The domain doesn't exist.

Answer (score 6):

It's not standard C, but `gettimeofday()` is present in both SysV and BSD derived systems, and is in POSIX.  It returns the time since the epoch in a `struct timeval`:

```
struct timeval {
    time_t      tv_sec;     /* seconds */
    suseconds_t tv_usec;    /* microseconds */
};
```

Answer (score 5):

For Unix and Linux you could use [gettimeofday](https://linux.die.net/man/2/gettimeofday).

For Win32 you could use [GetSystemTimeAsFileTime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/sysinfoapi/nf-sysinfoapi-getsystemtimeasfiletime) and then convert it to time_t + milliseconds:

```
void FileTimeToUnixTime(FILETIME ft, time_t* t, int* ms)
{
  LONGLONG ll = ft.dwLowDateTime | (static_cast<LONGLONG>(ft.dwHighDateTime) << 32);
  ll -= 116444736000000000;
  *ms = (ll % 10000000) / 10000;
  ll /= 10000000;
  *t = static_cast<time_t>(ll);
}
```

Comment: gettimeofday() does what is needed. Here's a code example: http://www.docs.hp.com/en/B9106-90009/gettimeofday.2.html

So what OSes is Aman trying to support?

Comment: First link is dead.

Comment: @aioobe Hence why it's [site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259/217640) [policy](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/7659/217640) to quote the relevant passage of (or summarize) any link you include.

Comment: The second link is dead

Answer (score 2):

```
    // the system time
    SYSTEMTIME systemTime;
    GetSystemTime( &systemTime );

    // the current file time
    FILETIME fileTime;
    SystemTimeToFileTime( &systemTime, &fileTime );

    // filetime in 100 nanosecond resolution
    ULONGLONG fileTimeNano100;
    fileTimeNano100 = (((ULONGLONG) fileTime.dwHighDateTime) << 32) + fileTime.dwLowDateTime;

    //to milliseconds and unix windows epoche offset removed
    ULONGLONG posixTime = fileTimeNano100/10000 - 11644473600000;
    return posixTime;
```

Comment: [How do I write a good answer to a question? - Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/7662/217640). Your answer seems to be heavily reliant on a specific OS/environment (what about non-POSIX environments?), and lacks context. For example, POSIX cstdlib does not use all-capital type names for *any* of the datatypes it specifies--those had to be defined elsewhere. You appear to be using a library. It's fine to mention that "this answer pertains to X class of systems with Y library, I am not sure how to do it with Z system, though", but code-only answers like this are hardly useful

Answer (score 1):

[Unix time or Posix time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) is the time in *seconds* since the epoch you mentioned.

[bzabhi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/227665/bzabhi)'s answer is correct: you simply multiply the Unix timestamp by 1000 to get milliseconds.

Be aware that all millisecond values returned by relying on the Unix timestamp will be *multiples* of 1000 (like 12345678000). The resolution is still only 1 second.

*You can't get the fraction part*

The comment from Pavel is correct also. The Unix timestamp **does not take into account leap seconds**. This makes it even less wise to rely on a conversion to milliseconds.

Comment: Any other library which can get the exact milisecond including its fraction part?????

Comment: The Unix timestamp is about as fundamental as we can go. It must be that the designers of Unix thought one second resolution was enough. Then again the overhead of maintaining a 1ms resolution was probably beyond early Unix systems.