# C++ retrieving the number of ms since jan 01 1970: cannot open source file sys/time.h

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I am trying to get the number of ms since jan 01 1970 using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19555121/how-to-get-current-timestamp-in-milliseconds-since-1970-just-the-way-java-gets).  However when I try to compile I get

```
"Error: cannot open source file 'sys/time.h'"
```

I am using Visual Studio.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using C++ 11, you can use `std::chrono`.

```
#include <chrono>

long long GetUnixTimeChrono()
{
    auto timeSinceEpoch = std::chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch();
    return std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(timeSinceEpoch).count();
}
```

Otherwise, you can do this:

```
#include <Windows.h>

long long GetUnixTime()
{
    SYSTEMTIME sysUnixEpoch;
    sysUnixEpoch.wYear = 1970;
    sysUnixEpoch.wMonth = 1;
    sysUnixEpoch.wDayOfWeek = 4;
    sysUnixEpoch.wDay = 1;
    sysUnixEpoch.wHour = 0;
    sysUnixEpoch.wMinute = 0;
    sysUnixEpoch.wSecond = 0;
    sysUnixEpoch.wMilliseconds = 0;

    FILETIME unixEpoch;
    SystemTimeToFileTime(&sysUnixEpoch, &unixEpoch);

    ULARGE_INTEGER unixEpochValue;
    unixEpochValue.HighPart = unixEpoch.dwHighDateTime;
    unixEpochValue.LowPart = unixEpoch.dwLowDateTime;

    FILETIME systemTime;
    GetSystemTimeAsFileTime(&systemTime);

    ULARGE_INTEGER systemTimeValue;
    systemTimeValue.HighPart = systemTime.dwHighDateTime;
    systemTimeValue.LowPart = systemTime.dwLowDateTime;

    long long diffHundredNanos = systemTimeValue.QuadPart - unixEpochValue.QuadPart;
    return diffHundredNanos / 10000;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The `sys/time.h` header is a POSIX header and as such is not typically found on a Windows machine, and certainly not in a Windows SDK. For Visual Studio you need to include `time.h` rather than `sys/time.h`, as described in the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1f4c8f33.aspx).

But the functions in the Visual Studio `time.h` don't give you millisecond precision. There is not `gettimeofday()`. The best you can do is Unix time in seconds. Now, millisecond precision Unix time on Windows was the subject of this question: [How can i get UTCTime in millisecond since January 1, 1970 in c language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1952290/how-can-i-get-utctime-in-milisecond-since-january-1-1970-in-c-language). However, the accepted answer is dire and really should be deleted.

After a bit more diffing, I think you will find what you need here: [Convert Windows Filetime to second in Unix/Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6161776/convert-windows-filetime-to-second-in-unix-linux). The workflow goes like this:

1. Call `GetSystemTime()` to get the system time.
2. Call `SystemTimeToFileTime` to convert to file time.
3. Use the conversion detailed in the above link to convert from file time to Unix time.

I think this is what you need, but bear in mind I am not remotely fluent in C++:

```
#include <windows.h>

long long GetUnixTime()
{
    const long long WINDOWS_TICK = 10000000LL;
    const long long SEC_TO_UNIX_EPOCH = 11644473600LL;

    SYSTEMTIME st;
    GetSystemTime(&st);

    FILETIME ft;
    if (!SystemTimeToFileTime(&st, &ft))
        return -1;

    ULARGE_INTEGER uli;
    uli.LowPart = ft.dwLowDateTime;
    uli.HighPart = ft.dwHighDateTime;
    return uli.QuadPart / WINDOWS_TICK - SEC_TO_UNIX_EPOCH;
}
```

Comment: This still didn't solve the problem since gettimeofday() is now not recognized (I am copying verbatim from the solution in the link i provided).

Comment: There's a difference between solving your problem, and answering your question. Anyway, I think the final link that I offer should do the trick.

Comment: don't append wMilliseconds! They are already counted in the code above.

Comment: +1 I'd suggest to use `GetSystemTimeAsFileTime()` as replacement for `GetSystemTime()` and `SystemTimeToFileTime()` to make the code even smarter.